# How to check two words of a string separately with Startswith etc. and filter it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter, startswith

```
const people = [
      { first: 'John', last: 'Doe', year: 1991, continent: "North America" },
      { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', year: 1990, continent: "Americas" },
      { first: 'Jahn', last: 'Deo', year: 1986, continent: "Europe" },
      { first: 'Jone', last: 'Deo', year: 1992, continent: "North America" },
      { first: 'Jhan', last: 'Doe', year: 1989, continent: "Asia" },
      { first: 'Jeon', last: 'Doe', year: 1992, continent: "Europe" },
      { first: 'Janh', last: 'Edo', year: 1984, continent: "North America" },
      { first: 'Jean', last: 'Edo', year: 1981, continent: "North America"},
];
```

I am able to check first word of continent with StartsWith but I want to find out if I look for "Am" it returns "North America" and "South America".

This is how I do currently;

```
const continent = people.filter(e =>
                e.continent.startsWith("Am")
            );
```

This returns an empty []. I tried to use `split("")` but then it creates an array and I have an error startswith doesn't exist in array. How can I check the second word in the string if it includes the certain string? In the end, I want to keep only objects of the array include "America", "North America", "South America".

Comment: You want to use [`includes("America")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the string contains your filter and not check if the string starts with your filter.

Comment: The easiest way was to make use of regular expressions. For the given example it would be something like this `e => RegExp('\\b' + 'Am').test(e.continent)`. (\b matches word boundaries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use filter and split. Also use `some`. `split` will create a array then use `some` to find if any on the element in that array starts with the required matching characters.

For example on `split` `North America` will be `['North','America']` and `some` will check if any element in this array satisfy the requirement , then it will return `true`

```js
const people = [{
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe',
    year: 1991,
    continent: "North America"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jane',
    last: 'Doe',
    year: 1990,
    continent: "Americas"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jahn',
    last: 'Deo',
    year: 1986,
    continent: "Europe"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jone',
    last: 'Deo',
    year: 1992,
    continent: "North America"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jhan',
    last: 'Doe',
    year: 1989,
    continent: "Asia"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jeon',
    last: 'Doe',
    year: 1992,
    continent: "Europe"
  },
  {
    first: 'Janh',
    last: 'Edo',
    year: 1984,
    continent: "North America"
  },
  {
    first: 'Jean',
    last: 'Edo',
    year: 1981,
    continent: "North America"
  },
];


const continent = people.filter((e) => {
  const continentName = e.continent.split(' ');
  const startWith = continentName.some(item => item.startsWith("Am"));
  if (startWith) {
    return e
  }
});

console.log(continent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a regular expression which looks for a starting word with a previous starting string or whitespace.

```js
const
    people = [{ first: 'John', last: 'Doe', year: 1991, continent: "North America" }, { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', year: 1990, continent: "Americas" }, { first: 'Jahn', last: 'Deo', year: 1986, continent: "Europe" }, { first: 'Jone', last: 'Deo', year: 1992, continent: "North America" }, { first: 'Jhan', last: 'Doe', year: 1989, continent: "Asia" }, { first: 'Jeon', last: 'Doe', year: 1992, continent: "Europe" }, { first: 'Janh', last: 'Edo', year: 1984, continent: "North America" }, { first: 'Jean', last: 'Edo', year: 1981, continent: "North America"}],
    continent = people.filter(e => /(^|\s)Am/.test(e.continent));

console.log(continent);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ... lets combine our approaches ... since the OP might most probably be forced to dynamically create the regexp you might consider changing the `filter` related one-liner to either  `e => RegExp('(^|\\s)' + 'Am').test(e.continent)`or `RegExp('\\b' + 'Am').test(e.continent)`

Comment: Thank you, this is really useful and short! I have been searching how to not match when searching '.' because if I search '.' instead of 'Am', it returns all objects. How can I avoid that in regex?

Comment: the dot is any character. for using it literally, you need to escape it like `\.`.

Comment: thanks! yes, I was reading it now. How can I add into this structure RegExp('(^|\\s)' + '.') to be able escape from dot or *?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this.

```
var filtered = people.filter(function(it) {
    return it.continent.split(" ").reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a || b.startsWith("Am")
    }, false);
});
```

`filtered` will contain your desired output. This is the closest thing to your original code that does what you intend.